# My character moves only to the left without me doing anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character moves by itself without me doing anything, I have already reviewed the movement code several times, I even tried trying other methods with the same function (moving the character) and they all continued with the same problem (The code worked in yes, but my character moves infinitely by itself) I also installed and uninstalled versions of unity client to see if it could be solved by doing that but no

Do you think it could be a problem with the unity client? I am using version 2022 although in version 2021 and 2019 the same thing happened to me, could it be some configuration that I touched by accident? And if so, how do I return it to its original state?

Here is one of the codes I used, I also tried with CharacterController

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private new Rigidbody rigidbody;

    public float speed = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float hor = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float ver = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (hor != 0.0f || ver != 0.0f)
        {
            Vector3 dir = transform.forward * ver + transform.right * hor;

            rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + dir * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }


    }
}
```

And this is other script i tried using CharacterController

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float horizontalMove;
public float verticalMove;
public CharacterController player;

public float playerspeed;

void Start() {
    player = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    
}

void Update() {

    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    player.Move(new Vector3(horizontalMove, 0, verticalMove) * playerspeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}

I used when I saw that they did not solve the problem, I saved and deleted from my project, right now I created a new file to focus on finding solutions to the problem, since with any script to move the character this happens to me with rigidbody or CharacterController
I tried using the Debug.Log to find out if what was the problem but it didn't work either
It sits on flat ground, I also turned gravity off but the problem was still working. No external forces are applied to the rigid body as it is a new project I made to focus on this problem.
I don't have any other script currently in my project. This is the CharacterController script that I used and it didn't work for me, I'll give you the link where I got it too

CharacterController: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvvTDkJvBfA&t=1296s

RigidBody: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oi8GzAm49k

I would be very grateful if you help me solve this error that I have, I have been searching for a solution or explanation for two days in forums and youtube videos

Comment: Thank you very much and excuse me, now I edit it and put the code

Comment: @kipt have you tried adding some `Debug.Log($" Horizontal: {hor},  Vertial: {ver} ")` statements to see what the `hor` and `ver` values are?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it, I'll try any possible solution they tell me, I don't have that much experience programming

Comment: As said before me, try printing out the vertical and horizontal values you get to see maybe the problem is with the keyboard and the input itself

Answer (score 0):

While this is not exactly an answer, this is the first step you could take to determine what the problem is, as per the comment above:

```cs
void Update ( )
{
    var hor = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    var ver = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    // If you're using a joystick that isn't quite calibrated, you might be getting a slight reading?
    // Here we could check if the value is ALMOST 0:
    // hor = Mathf.Approximately(hor, 0) ? 0 : hor;

    if ( hor != 0f || ver != 0f )
    {
        Debug.Log ( $"Horizontal: {hor}. Vertical {ver}." );
        var dir = (transform.forward * ver) + (transform.right * hor);
        rigidbody.MovePosition ( transform.position + Time.deltaTime * speed * dir );
    }

    var accumulatedForce = rigidbody.GetAccumulatedForce ( );
    if ( accumulatedForce != Vector3.zero )
    {
        Debug.Log ( $"accumulatedForce: {accumulatedForce}" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much I will open my project in unity, I will test it and I will tell you the results

Thanks for taking the trouble.

Comment: I already tried what you told me and it keeps giving the same error, the (Player) goes to the left of the screen without me touching the a s d w keys, but the keys themselves work if I press them and they go horizontally and vertically but it goes to the left as well
Is it some error from my client or configuration that I have? although I don't think so since it doesn't touch anything itself, and the same thing happened to me in 3 versions

Comment: @kipt in that case, we're going to have to dig deeper and you're going to have to supply more information. For example, does your RigidBody sit on a ground that is sloped? Are there any external forces being applied to the RigidBody? What other code scripts might ALSO be affecting the RigidBody? I've also updated the code to try and help us see what forces are being applied to the object.

Comment: I don't think so since the scripts that I used when I saw that they did not solve the problem I saved and deleted from my project, right now I created a new file to focus on finding solutions to the problem, since with any script to move the character it happens to me this with rigidbody or CharacterController, I can pass you a script that uses CharacterController and answering the questions:

No, it sits on flat ground, I also deactivated gravity but the problem still worked.
No external forces are being applied to the rigidbody since it is a new project that I did to focus on this problem

Comment: I don't have any other script currently in my project

I'll give you the CharacterController script that I used and it didn't work for me, I got it from YouTube but I don't think it affects anything

Comment: I send the script but it appears all together, how do I formally send it?

Comment: @kipt you can add all the information to your question. You should also include a link to the YouTube video to compare with.